# Change page title with Ajax returns 'undefined'

Tags: ajax, web, load, title

I need to get `title` of the `href` variable:

```
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            success:function(response) {
                document.title = $(response).find('title').html();
                window.history.pushState('', '', href);
            },
        })
    })
```

Сhanging `url` works carefully, but the page `title` shows `undefined`.

Comment: Please to track your variables with console.log and edit your question

Comment: it solved , i changed find with filter !

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are expecting `response` to be in a format acceptable as input of the `jQuery` function (A string containing a selector expression). While `response` can only be XML, JSON, HTML, or script. According to [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), if `dataType` is not specified, an Intelligent Guess will be performed. In your question, we don't know what is the format returned by AJAX.

In the case of your data returned as HTML, I think you should crawl this HTML to get the `<title>` tag, which will require more code.

In the case of data returned as JSON, you can parse this data from the response and put it in `document.title`. ( of course, the logic that adds the page `title` server-side as part of JSON response should be implemented).

Anyways, I believe   `$(response).find('title').html();` will not efficently get the title of the new AJAX-returned content.